# LSTM Time-Series produces shifted forecast?

Tags: keras, neural-network, deep-learning, time-series, prediction

I am doing a time-series forecast with an LSTM NN and Keras. As input features, there are two variables (precipitation and temperature), and the one target to be predicted is groundwater-level.

It seems to be working quite all right, though there is a serious offset between the actual data and the output (see image).

Now I've read that this is can be a classic sign of the network not working, as it seems to be mimicking the output and

> what the model is actually doing is that when predicting the value at
> time “t+1”, it simply uses the value at time “t” as its prediction https://towardsdatascience.com/how-not-to-use-machine-learning-for-time-series-forecasting-avoiding-the-pitfalls-19f9d7adf424

However, this is not actually possible in my case, as the target-values are not used as input variables. I am using a multivariate time-series with two features, independent of the output feature.
Also, the predicted values are not offset in future (t+1) but rather seem to lag behind (t-1).

Does anyone know what could cause this problem? [image]

This is the complete code of my network:

```py
# Split in Input and Output Data 
x_1 = data[['MeanT']].values
x_2 = data[['Precip']].values
y = data[['Z_424A_6857']].values

# Scale Data
x = np.hstack([x_1, x_2])
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
x = scaler.fit_transform(x)

scaler_out = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
y = scaler_out.fit_transform(y)

# Reshape Data
x_1, x_2, y = H.create2feature_data(x_1, x_2, y, window)
train_size = int(len(x_1) * .8)
test_size = int(len(x_1)) #  * .5

x_1 = np.expand_dims(x_1, 2) # 3D tensor with shape (batch_size, timesteps, input_dim) // (nr. of samples, nr. of timesteps, nr. of features)
x_2 = np.expand_dims(x_2, 2)
y = np.expand_dims(y, 1)

# Split Training Data
x_1_train = x_1[:train_size]
x_2_train = x_2[:train_size]
y_train = y[:train_size]

# Split Test Data
x_1_test = x_1[train_size:test_size]
x_2_test = x_2[train_size:test_size]
y_test = y[train_size:test_size]

# Define Model Input Sets
inputA = Input(shape=(window, 1))
inputB = Input(shape=(window, 1))

# Build Model Branch 1
branch_1 = layers.GRU(16, activation=act, dropout=0, return_sequences=False, stateful=False, batch_input_shape=(batch, 30, 1))(inputA)
branch_1 = layers.Dense(8, activation=act)(branch_1)
#branch_1 = layers.Dropout(0.2)(branch_1)
branch_1 = Model(inputs=inputA, outputs=branch_1) 

# Build Model Branch 2
branch_2 = layers.GRU(16, activation=act, dropout=0, return_sequences=False, stateful=False, batch_input_shape=(batch, 30, 1))(inputB)
branch_2 = layers.Dense(8, activation=act)(branch_2)
#branch_2 = layers.Dropout(0.2)(branch_2)
branch_2 = Model(inputs=inputB, outputs=branch_2) 

# Combine Model Branches
combined = layers.concatenate([branch_1.output, branch_2.output])
  
# apply a FC layer and then a regression prediction on the combined outputs
comb = layers.Dense(6, activation=act)(combined)
comb = layers.Dense(1, activation="linear")(comb)
  
# Accept the inputs of the two branches and then output a single value
model = Model(inputs=[branch_1.input, branch_2.input], outputs=comb)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse', H.r2_score])

model.summary()

# Training
model.fit([x_1_train, x_2_train], y_train, epochs=epoch, batch_size=batch, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[tensorboard])
model.reset_states()

# Evaluation
print('Train evaluation')
print(model.evaluate([x_1_train, x_2_train], y_train))

print('Test evaluation')
print(model.evaluate([x_1_test, x_2_test], y_test))

# Predictions
predictions_train = model.predict([x_1_train, x_2_train])
predictions_test = model.predict([x_1_test, x_2_test])

predictions_train = np.reshape(predictions_train, (-1,1))
predictions_test = np.reshape(predictions_test, (-1,1))

# Reverse Scaling
predictions_train = scaler_out.inverse_transform(predictions_train)
predictions_test = scaler_out.inverse_transform(predictions_test)

# Plot results
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 6))
plt.plot(orig_data, color='blue', label='True GWL')  
plt.plot(range(train_size), predictions_train, color='red', label='Predicted GWL (Training)')
plt.plot(range(train_size, test_size), predictions_test, color='green', label='Predicted GWL (Test)')
plt.title('GWL Prediction')  
plt.xlabel('Day')  
plt.ylabel('GWL')  
plt.legend()  
plt.show()
```

I am using a batch size of 30 timesteps, and a lookback of 90 timesteps, with a total data size of around 7500-time steps.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :-) Thank you!

Comment: some things are not clear here. are you using time steps between [t-90:t] to predict t+1 step or a value say 10 days after t, i.e. t+10? Also, what is your accuracy on your training set? it seems that your model has not been properly trained as there is a big difference between predicted and actual training data points, i.e. high bias. You could have high bias if you are using early stopping though...

Comment: @euren Hey, thanks for the comment. Yes I am using time steps between [t-90:t] to predict t+1 step. The Accuracy for my training set is around 0.002 (mse) and around 0.014 (mse) for the test set. I am not using early stopping so far. The difference between predicted and actual training data is whats bothering me, or, the shift is whats bothering me. Do you know how I could remedy that shift?

Comment: If you are not using early stopping then loss of mse 0.02 is high, usually you should get e-5 or e-6 easily. This is also demonstrated with the shift in the train predicted and real. Maybe you are not shifting the data properly, i.e. preprocessing. Maybe you should check there.

Comment: also 90 days is too long, LSTMs without attention cannot effectively work over this long range. Even with attention, they do not work to the most of their potential. I suggest you change to 10 time steps instead.

Comment: @eugen: Ok. I am shifting in preprocessing with my create2feature_data-function `def create2feature_data(x_1, x_2, y, window_size = 1):
    inp_1, inp_2, out = [], [], []    
    for i in range(window_size, len(x_1)):  
        inp_1.append(x_1[i-window_size:i, 0])
        inp_2.append(x_2[i-window_size:i, 0])
        out.append(y[i, 0])        
    return(np.array(inp_1), np.array(inp_2), np.array(out))` Thats where I create my sliding window for the data. Otherwise Im not shifting. What could I do different in the preprocessing?

Answer (score 0):

Probably my answer is not relevant two years later, but I had a similar issue when experimenting with LSTM encoder-decoder model. I solved my problem by scaling the input data in the range `-1 .. 1` instead of `0 .. 1` as in your example.