# In LSTM, the predicted value is shifted to the right by one compared to the actual value

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I am doing a time series forecasting with LSTM. As an input feature, the air pollution level in the last 5 hours and the target is to predict the pollution level in the next hour.

It seems to work well, but there is a serious discrepancy between the actual data and the prediction data (see image).
It's like the prediction graph is shifted to the right compared to the actual graph.

What could be causing this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgcWS.png)

my  code is :

```py
#normalization
main_scaled=sc.fit_transform(dataset_main)
print("main-scaled : \n",main_scaled)

#partitioning
training_set_scaled = main_scaled[0:16560]
print("train_scaled: \n",training_set_scaled)

validation_set_scaled=main_scaled[16560:23160]
print("validation_scaled: \n",validation_set_scaled)

test_set_scaled=main_scaled[23160:28200]
print("test_scaled: \n",test_set_scaled)

#make x_train and y_train
x=[]
x_train = []
y_train = []
time_step=5
for i in range(time_step, 16560):
    x=training_set_scaled[i-time_step:i,0]
    y=training_set_scaled[i,0]

    if(np.isnan(x).any()==False and math.isnan(y)==False):
      x_train.append(x)
      y_train.append(y)
x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)
print("x_train is :",(x_train))

x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1))
print("x-train: \n",x_train ,"\n y-train:",y_train)

#make x_val and y_val (validation)
inputs1 = main_scaled[len(training_set_scaled)-5:len(training_set_scaled)+len(validation_set_scaled):]
print("inputs1 :\n ", inputs1) #Adding the last 5 data of the training data to the beginning of the validation data

x2=[]
x_val = []
y_val = []
time_step=5
for i in range(time_step, 6605):
    x2=inputs1[i-time_step:i,0]
    y2=inputs1[i,0]
    if(np.isnan(x2).any()==False and math.isnan(y2)==False):
      x_val.append(x2)
      y_val.append(y2)
x_val, y_val = np.array(x_val), np.array(y_val)
x_val = np.reshape(x_val, (x_val.shape[0], x_val.shape[1], 1))

#define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units = 32, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (x_train.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(units = 16, return_sequences = False))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(units = 1))

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error' , metrics=['mae'])

history=model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 9, batch_size = 32, validation_data=(x_val,y_val))
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57927187/lstm-time-series-produces-shifted-forecast) help?